# How can i append code to a certain location in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I am trying to create a chat system for my school's pupil shared folder but I'm having some trouble displaying already imputed text by the users

before inputting any text to the chat system it looks like this

```
:AddNewText
set /p Desc=
echo :%Text: =% >> "%~F0"
echo echo %Desc% >> "%~F0"
set /a Text=%Text%+1

:StartOfText
echo Welcome to the Chat Box
echo.

:EndOfText
goto AddnewText
```

But after I input text it looks like this

```
:AddNewText
set /p Desc=
echo :%Text: =% >> "%~F0"
echo echo %Desc% >> "%~F0"
set /a Text=%Text%+1

:StartOfText
echo Welcome to the Chat Box
echo.

:EndOfText
goto AddnewText


:2 
echo This is a test 
:3 
echo This is another test 
:4 
echo and another test
```

How do I change the code so that :2,:3 and :4 are created in between :StartOfText and :EndOfText

Comment: The code is writing (appending) to the .bat file that is running. `>> "%~F0"` I doubt if this will work well.

Comment: Is there another way to get the same results

Comment: Why does the code need to write into the code? There does not appear to be anything in the code that will use the text produced. I do not understand the goal.

Comment: The goal is to collect multiple inputs of text and then display them in the order that they were imputed to create a chat area for my friends at school as the pupil shared folder is accessible by everyone meaning that they can all input text into my code to be able to talk with other pupils

Comment: I suggest that the text input be written to another file. If the student can remember to run `chatbox.bat` then they can remember to `TYPE chatbox.log`.

Comment: Ok thank you I shall research into it